# Pass Dropdownlistfor selected value to controller on selected item changed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Trying to pass the selected value which is studentid in this case to BeginForm.

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DDSubmit", "Home",new { id=Model.studentID}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.studentID, Model.DDList, "Please Select",new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

### Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult DDSubmit(int id)
    {
        var info = (from r in entity.STUDENTS where r.Student_Id == id select r).ToList();
        return View(info);            
    }
```

### Model

```
public class DDModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> DDList { get; set; }
    public int studentID { get; set; }
    public string studentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? If you POST method has a parameter for the model, then its `studentID` property will be bound with the value of the selected option

Comment: I am getting always zero in action method, irrespective of my item selection from dropdown

Comment: Then its probably a field and not a property. you have not shown any of the relevant code (your model or the controller methods!)

Comment: I have added the model and controller action

Comment: That makes no sense. You have shown a GET method that returns a collection and a view that has a model which is clearly not a collection so that code would not even compile. And you have not shown the POST method (and not related, but delete the pointless  `new { id=Model.studentID}` in your `BeginForm()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out

### View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("DDSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.studentID, Model.DDList, "Please Select",new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

### Action

```
public ActionResult DDSubmit(DDModel ddlist)
    {
        int id = ddlist.studentID;
        var info = (from r in entity.STUDENTS where r.Student_Id == id select r).ToList();
        return View(info);            
    }
```